# Multithreading in Objective-C

Tags: iphone, objective-c, multithreading

I'm trying to run a method in the background, but it still blocks the program.
This is my code:

```
    - (void)viewDidLoad
    {
        [super viewDidLoad];
        self.MessagesList=[[MessagesArray alloc] init];

        [self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(backgroundMethod) withObject:nil];
    }


    -(void)backgroundMethod
    {
        if ([MessagesList updateFromServer]){
            [self.Table reloadData];
             CFRunLoopRun();
    }
}
```

While updateFromServer sends an HTTP request to the server and waiting for a response, the server delays the response by 10 seconds, and the result is that the whole program is delayed by 10 seconds too. Can you correct me?

Updating: I added a runloop line, but the problem remains the same. The HTTP request is asynchronous, but still - the whole program waits until the server responds. This is my updateFromServer method:

```
responseData = [NSMutableData data];
[self setBaseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://localhost:8000/messages/views/new_messages/"]];
NSURLRequest *request =
    [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://localhost:8000/messages/views/new_messages/"]];
NSURLConnection* connection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
return TRUE;
```

How can I make it asynchronous for real?

Comment: How about using NSThread instead?

Comment: I tried it too. nothing changes. thanks

Answer (score 1):

Always update the UI on the main thread, `[self.Table reloadData]` doesn't update on the background thread. How are you sending HTTP request? NSURLConnection asynchronously or synchronous?

If it's a synchronous connection then it blocks the thread it's running on until the response is received.

Comment: when I run a synchronous request it blocks it. asynchronous just doesn't run (it runs if I call it from the main thread, but then the if statement blocks because it's waiting for response).
any way - how do I update UI from the main thread if I need to all-the-time check updates from server?

Comment: From a background thread, you can call -[NSObject performSelectorOnMainThread:withObject:waitUntilDone:] on any NSObject. I have done this in many places to great effect.

Comment: @AmitHagin, Add a run loop for your background thread asynchronous NSURLConnection.

Comment: it doesn't help. for some reason it works like a synchronous request.  I added some more code... can you find the problem?